# ¿Cuál es el sujeto en la oración "si el tiempo me lo permite"?

Tags: sujeto

Hoy, estaba leyendo [este artículo](https://www.heraldo.es/noticias/nacional/2022/10/16/alberto-monaco-dara-nombre-arte-rupestre-cantabria-espana-1606184.html) y encontré esta oración

> "…, si el tiempo me lo permite, estaría muy feliz de volver para esta inauguración"

Tengo una pregunta: ¿Cuál es el sujeto en la oración "si el tiempo me lo permite"?

Yo creo que el sujeto es "el tiempo", pero también puede ser que "el tiempo" sea el objeto de la oración por el "lo".

Answer (score 3):

La oración:

- Si el tiempo me lo permite, estaría muy feliz de volver para esta inauguración

es una oración compuesta por una proposición principal:

"estaría muy feliz de volver para esta inauguración"

cuyo sujeto tácito es "yo" (***yo** estaría muy feliz ...*)

y una proposición subordinada condicional:

"si el tiempo me lo permite"

cuyo sujeto es "**el tiempo**".

- El tiempo me permite volver para esta inauguración.

El tiempo: sujeto / me: complemento indirecto (= a mí) / permite: verbo / volver para esta inauguración: complemento directo (= lo: el tiempo me permite eso/algo, el tiempo me lo permite)

(Aclaro que este análisis responde al enfoque de la gramática tradicional.)

Answer (score 0):

> {Lo esperamos todos dentro de unos meses } **y** { el señor presidente ya me ha invitado, muy generosamente y muy gentilmente, a venir a la apertura de este centro } **y** { por supuesto que, si el tiempo me lo permite, estaría muy feliz de volver para esta inauguración}.

> {Por supuesto **que** {, si el tiempo me lo permite, estaría muy feliz de volver para esta inauguración}.}

> {**Si** {el tiempo me lo permite,} estaría muy feliz de volver para esta inauguración.}

> El tiempo me lo permite.

Antes de hacer nada, conviene aclarar que deberíamos comenzar por reconocer las cláusulas que forman la oración completa. Supongo que sabes cómo hacerlo, ya que has preguntado específicamente por la última cláusula independiente. Dentro de ella hay dos cláusulas subordinadas anidadas: la primera es introducida por "*que*" mientras que la segunda es introducida por "*si*". Sobre esta última oración elemental, que es la prótasis de un condicional, efectuaremos el análisis sintáctico.

Para poder identificar correctamente al sujeto, identificamos el verbo de la oración: es "*permite*". Tu hipótesis inicial fue que el sujeto era "*el tiempo*". Ahora, realizamos mi prueba de oro favorita: pregúntate *¿Qué ocurriría si cambiara de número o género a mi supuesto sujeto?* Por ejemplo, intenta con:

> **Mis padres** me lo **permiten**.

Efectivamente, vemos que el verbo tuvo que modificarse para poder concordar con el nuevo sujeto; por lo tanto tu suposición es correcta. Así, nos quedará que:

[image]